# Remove duplicate array elements in C

Tags: c, arrays

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [remove duplicate elements in an array in O(n) in C/C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3432760/remove-duplicate-elements-in-an-array-in-on-in-c-c)

How can I remove duplicate elements from an array?

#### Before

```
array [ ] = {1,2,3,4,5,1,2,4,9,0,0}
```

#### After

```
array [ ] = {0,1,2,3,4,5,9}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. Sort the array using your favorite sorting algorithm.
2. Walk through the array and eliminate duplicates - if a value is the same one as the previous one, keep going forward until you get a new value and then copy it back.

Answer (score 1):

Use hash table and store each element into hash table. This way you will remove duplicates. This will give you O(n) complexity but you will have to add hash table support.

Comment: Quite a bit of overhead in a C application.

Comment: And not O(n), at least not for CS purposes. A carefully crafted input would, in the worst case, put a fixed proportion of the values into the same hash bucket.

Answer (score 1):

Given that you have an array of integers, and that you know their exact bounds, you can create a lookup table with a single pass over the input (use a bit vector if you have to constrict space) and then generate the array of unique entries with a single pass over the lookup table.

This would be a VERY SPECIFIC solution for a VERY SPECIFIC problem, but it does what you ask for.

Comment: Hm, since a lookup table could be considered a perfect (though not minimal) hash table this is basically just a more specific instance of ralu's answer. I think I'll upvote that, but judge for your self if you think this answer is "better"

Answer (score 0):

```
memset(index,0,sizeof(index));
for (int i=0; i<len(array); ++i)
   index[array[i]] = 1;
memset(array,0,sizeof(array));
for (int i=0,int j=0; i<len(index); ++i)
   if (index[i]) array[j++] = i;
```

Comment: sorry for poor format...i am newbie...